# How to create intent activity in recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I want to make move activity when thumbnail photo on click

but when I create the intent function in the section

```
 holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
```

it happened error, but if with Toast it can ..

how to handle it? This is my code in PhotoAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.List;


public class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
public List<Photo> PhotoList;

public PhotoAdapter(Context mContext, List<Photo> PhotoList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.PhotoList = PhotoList;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, rating;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        rating= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
    }


}

@Override
public PhotoAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.photo_card, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Photo movie = PhotoList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(movie.getName());
    holder.rating.setText("Tanggal Lahir : "+String.valueOf( movie.getRating()));


    Glide.with(mContext).load(movie.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });

    holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(movie.getName()=="Aditya Nanda Utama"){
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Anda memilih Saya",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Anda memilih "+movie.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return PhotoList.size();
}


private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_movie, popup.getMenu());

    popup.show();
}

}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: This line `if(movie.getName()=="Aditya Nanda Utama"){}` , you need not use `==` .You should use `equals` .

Comment: what is the actual problem. If i got your problem then you an use like this mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, desired.class)).

Comment: this solution is to create intent from adapter

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an interface in your adapter and have your activity(where you moving from) implement it.  The interface will have a method(listener), whenever you click the thumbnail use the instance of the activity(context) and call the method from the interface in the adapter.  Your activity will be triggered by the action and within your activity you will use intent.

See below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.List;


public class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
public List<Photo> PhotoList;
public MyAdapterListener myAdapterListener;

public PhotoAdapter(Context mContext, List<Photo> PhotoList, MyAdapterListener myAdapterListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.PhotoList = PhotoList;
    this.myAdapterListener = myAdapterListener;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, rating;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        rating= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
    }


}

@Override
public PhotoAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.photo_card, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Photo movie = PhotoList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(movie.getName());
    holder.rating.setText("Tanggal Lahir : "+String.valueOf( movie.getRating()));


    Glide.with(mContext).load(movie.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });

    holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //notify listener:
            myAdapterListener.onThumbnailClick();
            if(movie.getName()=="Aditya Nanda Utama"){
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Anda memilih Saya",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Anda memilih "+movie.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return PhotoList.size();
}


private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_movie, popup.getMenu());

    popup.show();
}

interface MyAdapterListener(){
    void onThumbnailClick();
}

}
```

On your activity:

```
public class MyActivity implements MyAdapterListener(){
...
@override
public void onThumbnailClick(){
  //Do your intent here

  Intent intent = ...

}

}
```